# Application of the spectral mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T:L^2((0,2)\rightarrow L^2((0,2))$, $(Tx)(t):=\begin{cases}
x(t+1), & 0<t<1\\
0,& 
\text{elsewhere} 
\end{cases}
$

Show that $T$ is well defined and $\sigma(T)=\sigma_p(T)=\{0\}$

Its easy to see that $(Tx)(t)\in L^2((0,2))$ if $x(t)\in L^2((0,2))$.

And now I have to show the other statement by using the spectral mapping theorem, which says that $\sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))$ with $f\in C(\sigma(T))$.

Can someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider the polynomial $f(X)=X^2.$